# Gathering every other string from list / line from file

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have been scripting for around two weeks, and have just learnt about reading from a file.

What I want to do is get every other entry from my original list and store it in a new list. Is this the best way to do it?

```
with open("test.txt",mode="r") as myfile:
File = myfile.read().splitlines()

Username = []

for i in range (len(File)):
    if File.index(File[i])%2 == 0 or File.index(File[i]) == 0:
        Username.append(File[i])
print(Username)
```

Please bear in mind that I have only studied Python for around ten hours so far - I'm quite happy that this even seemed to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least a couple ways to accomplish the same thing with less code.

### Slice Notation

Python has a way of iterating over every nth element of an array called [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation).  You can replace the entire loop with the following line

```
Username.extend(File[0::2])
```

What this basically means is to grab every `2`nd element starting at index `0` and add it to the `Username` array.

### The `range()` function

You can also use a different version of the `range()` function, that allows you to specify a start, end and step, list so.

```
for i in range(0, len(File), 2):
    Username.append(File[i])
```

The `range()` function is documented [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html).

Comment: ok thanks, would it have also worked if I just used range(0,len(File),2) or would that not work?

Comment: That would work, though it results in more code.  Choose what is most readable for you. :)  I updated my answer to mention using the `range()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

**`input_file`:**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
```

**Python:**

```
>>> with open("input_file") as f:
...     alternates = [line for i, line in enumerate(f) if not i % 2]
... 
>>> alternates
['Line 1\n', 'Line 3\n', 'Line 5\n', 'Line 7\n', 'Line 9\n']
```

Further reading: [the `enumerate()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: This seems a bit complex compared to the other methods, however I will look it up for some learning :D

Comment: @KieranLavelle one advantage of this method is that it doesn't store the whole file in a temporary list (which can be useful with large files), because iterating over a file is [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), and the lines you aren't interested in are just thrown away as the file is read.