# Slicing in python, advancing n lines after a line is copied and used

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm working on a script, see here:

```
from pysnap import Snapchat
import time

usnlist = raw_input('Enter file name: ')

s = Snapchat()

def filter(username, password):
    s.login(username, password)
    with open (usnlist, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            ok = False
            while not ok:
                try:
                    resp = s.add_friend(line.rstrip("\n"))
                    if 'object' in resp.keys():
                        # 'object' is contained within resp as a key
                        if resp['object']['type']:
                            # type is 1
                            with open ('private.txt', 'a') as f: f.write(resp['object']['name']+"\n")
                            print line.rstrip("\n") + "'s",
                            print "privacy settings are set to: FRIENDS"
                        else:
                            # type is 0
                            with open ('n-private.txt', 'a') as f: f.write(resp['object']['name']+"\n")
                            print line.rstrip("\n") + "'s",
                            print "privacy settings are set to: EVERYONE"
                        s.delete_friend(line)
                    else:
                        # no object in resp, so it's an invalid username
                        print line.rstrip("\n") + " is not a valid username"
                    ok = True
                except:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print "SNAPCHAT SERVER OVERLOAD - HOLD ON."

username = raw_input('Enter username: ')
password = raw_input('Enter password: ')

filter(username, password)
```

---

What I want now is be able to input a value lets call it `n` 
And when I input `n` the bot scrapes only every `n` line.

For example. `N = 2`.
The bot now only scrapes and inputs every second username from the list.

I came up with some stuff, like adding [0::2] to: `resp = s.add_friend(line.rstrip("\n"))`
Resulting in: `resp = s.add_friend(line[0::2].rstrip("\n"))`

But that did not work, bot went straight to `print "SNAPCHAT SERVER OVERLOAD - HOLD ON."`
Without checking any names.

I got the idea here:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155682/gathering-every-other-string-from-list-line-from-file
```

But the info given was not enough for me to get this to work.
**And I use python 2.7.8**

I wish there was just a way to tell python: "Get every `n` line in file"
Because that is basically what I am looking for.

If someone could help that'd be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you tried slices the line, not the file. Files don't have slice support, but the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module has a function for slicing arbitrary iterables:

```
import itertools
for line in itertools.islice(file, None, None, n):
    do_whatever_with(line)
```

The first two arguments are start and stop; a value of `None` for these arguments means the start and end of the input, since you can't omit them like you could in a regular slice. The third argument is the step.

Comment: kudos to you sir, IT WORKS :D

Answer (score 1):

To get every nth line in the file, replace this:

```
for line in file:
```

with:

```
for line in file.read().splitlines()[0::n]:
```